# OpenstreetMap + Leaflet and CloudMade

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, cloudmade

I use in my project OpenstreetMap and Leaflet.
Add a layer:

```
 L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/{my_key}/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
 attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href=\"http://cloudmade.com\">CloudMade</a>"
).addTo map
```

But today I received a letter from CloudMade.....

> As of May 1st we’ll be stopping service to your API key.  This means that CloudMade services like Map Tiles, Geocoding and Routing that you maybe using in your apps or websites will stop working.

**And how to add the map without this API?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cloudmade have decided to revoke access to their non-enterprise customers from May 2014. Other tilesets available are listed on OSM's wiki page [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles).

For instance, you can use the default OSM tileset as follows:

```
L.tileLayer(
    "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    ....
).addTo('map');
```

Comment: Thanx! Working :-)
But how add style, like in my example?

Comment: Unfortunately, the default OSM tileset has no separate styles available. If you have a particular need to style the map in a certain way, then you'll have to look into another provider like MapBox or go the difficult/painstaking method of creating your own tileserver.

Comment: Don't forget to check the *tile usage policy* of the new tile provider you are going to choose!